# Issue installing php intl

Tags: php, apache, centos, intl

I am using Virtualmin as Control Panel on Centos 7 and I need to install php intl extension to use prestashop.

I used this command

`yum --enablerepo=remi install php-intl`

I also added this to php.ini

`extension=intl.so`

but its not working. Note that `php -v` gives me

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Oct 22 2019 13:26:02)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

My website uses php v7.2 but the default servers php seems to be 5.4.45 (server uses multiple php versions)

I think that intl works for php 5.4 but not for 7.2 for sure.
Do I need to install it using other ways since I use multi php?

Comment: remove this extension=intl.so and check now.

Comment: this removed the error message but intl extension still not working for php 7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You load **intl.so** file twice in `/etc/php.d/` open all files and comment line with ";" in one of them where you load intl.so extension. Then restart Apache with `sudo systemctl restart httpd` and will work correctly

Comment: both of these directories have only 1 intl.so file

note that from info.php file the extension location is /opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules

which has no intl.so file. Should I copy this?

Comment: No, i correct my answer. Please check my answer now.

Comment: This location contains only one intl.ini file which content is

; Enable intl extension module
extension=intl.so

Comment: Open all files. You load intl.so extension in one of other files whose name in not intl.ini. Pleace check all files for intl.so. Then restart Apache with sudo systemctl restart httpd.

Comment: Comment line with ";" and tell me if my answer work and check "answered"

Comment: all of the other files seems to be correct...the issue should be elsewhere...

Comment: I just realised that the error `PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line ` is solved if I remove `extension=intl.so` from php.ini but intl still is not working for php7.2 after apache restart.

Comment: Remove extension=intl.so from php7.2 configuration file it's different php.ini file from php5